# How to generate words from excel cell using space delineation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to generate a list of space delineated words from an excel cell using a formula? For example, if I have the string:

"My name is Jack"

It should generate the words: "My", "name", "is", "Jack" in different cells.

But it should also not be dependent on the length of the string. So for example:

"I love squirrels"

Should generate the words: "I", "love", "squirrels" with the same formula.

Comment: This is a tall order to accomplish just using formulas. If you had a set structure you could use `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and `MID()` even if each word had a variable length. But as the number of words varies it might be difficult to impossible to accomplish. Is using a "User Defined Function" out of the question for your application?

Comment: @nbayly I'm trying to limit the amount of things running on my spreadsheet. This is a large spreadsheet located on a network and it can slow down quite a bit when I start running lots of macros on it.

Comment: @pnuts Oh, I didn't actually know there was such a tool in excel. It could definitely work for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your sentence in A1

```
B1:  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1, " ", REPT(" ",99)),MAX((COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*99,1),99))
```

and fill right as far as required.

Of course, if this does not need to be dynamic, as @pnuts commented, merely use text-to-columns with `space` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

How about a UDF?

Put this in a module in the workbook:

```
Function WordInString(MyWord As String, WordNum As Long)
    If Len(MyWord) - Len(Replace(MyWord, " ", "")) < WordNum - 1 Then
        WordInString = ""
    Else
        WordInString = Split(MyWord, " ")(WordNum - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Assuming your data is in column A row 1 and you want to start populating from column B onwards enter this formula in B1

```
=WordInString($A1,COLUMN(A1))
```

Drag across and down

Alternatively if you absolutely positively want a native Excel formula, try this:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),((COLUMN(A1)-1)*255)+1,255))
```

Same deal, assumes data starts in A1, put this in B1 and drag across and down.